# not found using http-server node.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, httpserver

I install http-server globally and still failed to load my angular app. I can start by doing `http-server C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\angularjsTDD\app` but when I visit localhost:8080 the terminal has a not found error message. The structure of my app can be found in githib

https://github.com/eldyvoon/angularTDD

Previously I was using express as backend but I want to try to use something simpler, but failed to get it to work.

If I visit index.html without using http-server like file:///C:/Users/Alex/Desktop/angularjs%20TDD/app/index.html I got error of `Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.` in chrome.

Comment: there is no server defined in APP repo

Comment: I usually `cd` into the directory and then use `http-server`. I assume your absolute path is wrong. In any case you could `cd` into the folder and type `dir` to see if your files are there.

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN but he's using `http-server` which is seperate (installed globally) and not a part of the project source.

Comment: @E.Sundin I tried `C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\angularjsTDD\app` and `C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\angularjsTDD` both doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to serve static files I think you need to place a folder called public in the directory you are serving from. Soi in your structure create a folder called public and put all of your files in there. Serving app should then load index.html from the public folder.

Answer (score 0):

I was using some path starting `http-server` which was wrong.

I've found the solution. The correct workaround would be

cd into my project, run `http-server`.